# is there a way to get an index formula to auto re reference the array after updating the array?

Tags: excel, vba, array-formulas

so I have an index-match formula that uses a second sheet in the same workbook to show data.
the formula looks like this

`=INDEX([sheet15]BUTTON!A:C,MATCH(INDIRECT(CELL("address")),[sheet15]BUTTON!A:A,0),3)`

This formula matches the selected cell in the sheet called button and then returns a cell to the right of the matched cell in the first sheet. I have multiple cells that return different parts of the row. i.e. the one above returns the 3rd column in the row and the others return the 4th the 5th the 7th and the 8th all that changes is the very last number before the bracket.

to get the info from the "button" sheet into the first sheet you simply select a cell (for context sake these are run numbers in my sheet) and then press f9 to refresh the sheet and it will return the info in the relevant boxes. then the next time you press f9 with a different run number selected the boxes change accordingly.

the problem I'm having is when I update the Button sheet with new info the formula wont return any of the matched info for the new data, all of the old data that was there before still works fine but any of the new data just returns #N/A as if the data isn't there to match it with. I can get it to work by clicking inside the cell that has the formula and then pressing enter which then brings up windows file finder and asks me to select an excel workbook to use as the array. I then select the same workbook and it will now return the new data.

so my question is, is there a way to re reference the array automatically when I update the data for each of the cells that has the formula in it (when I update the data it is using a macro on a completely different workbook that opens several workbooks and then copies and pastes the new data into them) and as I have the same set up of cells with formulas in around 14 workbooks I don't want to have to go through each one and re reference the array each time I update them.

any help would be appreciated.

So after playing around with recording macros I have managed to get it to the point where it will bring up a file finder window to select the sheet but I am having difficulty finding a way to get vba to select the file from the window. see the macro code below.

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

'
    Range("D4:M7").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = _
        "=INDEX([sheet15]BUTTON!C[-3]:C[-1],MATCH(INDIRECT(CELL(""address"")),[sheet15]BUTTON!C[-3],0),3)"
    Range("N4:X7").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = _
        "=INDEX([sheet15]BUTTON!C[-13]:C[-11],MATCH(INDIRECT(CELL(""address"")),[sheet15]BUTTON!C[-13],0),2)"
    Range("Y4:AD5").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = _
        "=INDEX([sheet15]BUTTON!C[-24]:C[-17],MATCH(INDIRECT(CELL(""address"")),[sheet15]BUTTON!C[-24],0),7)"
    Range("Y6:AD7").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = _
        "=INDEX([sheet15]BUTTON!C[-24]:C[-17],MATCH(INDIRECT(CELL(""address"")),[sheet15]BUTTON!C[-24],0),8)"
    Range("Y8").Select
End Sub
```

as I stated earlier when this runs it opens a file finder window and asks me to select a file. the name of the workbook is TOLEDO and that is also the file I want it to reference so how can I write select TOLEDO and then click the ok button? (please note I am not actually opening the sheet here I am simply picking a file to reference the array)

Comment: Are the values to be returned numbers?

Comment: @FaneDuru not all of them, one is just a number and the others are numbers and text

Comment: If you press Ctrl+Shift+Alt+F9 (or even just F9) does it update?

Comment: Do not use Indirect Function: it is really bad and volatile
If you speak a little german the danger of indirect:
https://www.online-excel.de/excel/singsel.php?f=171
and replace indirect with index
https://www.online-excel.de/excel/singsel.php?f=180

Comment: @TimWilliams no it doesn't unfortunately, I've just tried it

Comment: @RedHare the formula works as intended and the indirect function works as I want it to, the question is not about trying to get the formula to work it is about when I update the array the formula doesn't see the new data without re-referencing the array also I have no German so I cannot read the pages you have linked me although I appreciate the time, thanks.

Comment: @TimWilliams by the way the formula does update when I press f9. the question isn't about trying to get the formula to work. the formula works fine. the problem I'm having is when I update the array I then have to re reference the array in each of the cells that have the formula so I'm looking to find a way to get the formulas to automatically re reference the array after I have updated the array either through vba or some other method, just wanted to clarify that as after re reading your comment I think there was some confusion.

Comment: @Seb358 So, you do not  have correct setting for `Calculation`. It is on `Manual` in stead being on `Automate`. Try `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` and after that it will calculate without needing to pres `F9`. This is what `F9` does. It means `Calculate`... Or, fi you like calculating when you want, use `ActiveSheet.Calculate` at the end of the code.

Comment: @FaneDuru no calculation is on automatic already but as the formula uses the cell that is currently selected it needs f9 to be pressed to trigger an update but again the problem is not with the formula. the formula works fine. the problem I am having is when I update the array that the formula uses, it acts as though the new data in the array isn't there until I re reference the array I want to find a way to automatically re reference the array after I update the array as at the minute I have to select the cell with the formula click into the formula bar press enter then select the reference

Comment: Did you try `ActiveSheet.Calculate`? If it still not work, can you share such a workbook? If confidential, a dummy one, but tested that it behaves as you say...

Comment: @FaneDuru I am unsure how I would implement that in a formula? or would I put it in the workbook module? also yes I can share the workbook how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Simple write the suggested code line just before `End Sub`...

Comment: @FaneDuru this isn't a sub its a formula

Comment: Do you mean `Sub Macro2()` is a formula? If you consider it 'formula', please try placing there the suggested code line... Do you mean that you write the shown formulas (in code) manuals and face the problem you are talking about?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255377/discussion-between-seb358-and-faneduru).

Comment: I asked a clarification question two hours ago (in the chat window), but you did not answer it...

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this - any updates to the lookup table are reflected in the results of the index/match.  Would be useful if you could share a workbook which shows the problem.

Comment: @TimWilliams how would I go about sharing a workbook? also, like I have said previously the issue isn't with getting the formula to update that works fine, the problem I am having is when I update the array the formula wont bring any of the new info in until I manually re reference the formula array but it is easier to show so if I can send you the workbook I am sure you will see what I mean.

Comment: You can share a (redacted as necessary) workbook via google drive/one drive/dropbox etc.

Comment: If the `Calculation` is set on Automatic, maybe you do not have Events Enabled. And the `Calculate` event cannot be triggered. I would suggest the next two approaches:
1. Write a small `Sub` having a single code line: `Application.EnableEvents = true` and run it. Test if the problem has been solved.
2. Use the `Change` event of the sheet where you manually paste values with a simple code line, too: `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`  `Worksheets("sheet name where the formulas exist").Calculate` `End Sub`. 
In this way the Calculate event is forced to work, for any change.

Comment: @FaneDuru I think something has gotten lost in translation here, also I have been given a solution and I am currently waiting for them to post the answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I do not have a problem with that. But did you try the suggested solutions from my above comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this:

`=INDEX([sheet15]BUTTON!A:C,MATCH(INDIRECT(CELL("address")),[sheet15]BUTTON!A:A,0),3)`

You can write your formulas like this:

`=INDEX(BUTTON!C:C,MATCH(INDIRECT(CELL("address")),BUTTON!A:A,0),1)`

(without the `[sheet15]`) and that will fix the issue of including new data.

Also, to avoid having to press F9 every time you want new values to show, you can capture the selection event and auto-trigger a calculation:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    'recalculate if a cell in ColB is selected
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Columns("B")) Is Nothing Then Me.Calculate
End Sub
```